# In GCP, is there a canonical way to scrape data from an API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm building an application that will periodically pull data from several APIs and write them to cloud storage for later processing by Dataflow. There are many different ways to do this so I wanted to sanity check before I jumped in.

My plan is this:

- For each API, Cloud Scheduler will hit an endpoint for an App Engine app
- The app will create a Compute Engine VM instance with a startup script that pulls the data from the API and writes it to storage
- When done, the VM will hit another endpoint on the App Engine app that shuts down the VM.

Is this a reasonable way to perform this sort of action? Is there a simpler or more straight-forward method? Thank you in advance for the replies.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will cover all your needs but Cloud Scheduler can [schedule Compute Engine without App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/scheduling-instances-with-cloud-scheduler#set_up_the_instance) however it seems that you cannot create and delete the VM with this method.

Comment: This seems like a more standard way of doing things. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Scheduler can [schedule Compute Engine without App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/scheduling-instances-with-cloud-scheduler#set_up_the_instance) however it seems that you cannot create and delete the VM with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use App Engine cron jobs to schedule the tasks. Your App Engine app cron handler can simply run the script that pulls data from the APIs. Maybe I am missing something, why do you need to use a Compute Engine instance to run the script?

Comment: My thinking was that having a huge chunk of code in app engine is a less "cloud-y" way of solving the problem. Also VMs are cheaper than the app engine--particularly for this use-case where micro vm instances can do the job for essentially free (you get 720 hours a month which is way more than I need).